# Why doesn't this simple data initialisation function work in this vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a vue 3 component. The relevant script code below;

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */

export default {
  name: "BarExample",
  data: dataInitialisation,
  methods: {
    updateChart,
  }
};

function dataInitialisation()
{
  return {
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          //categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999],
          categories: [1991, 1992],
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [30, 40],
        }
      ]
    };
}
</script>
```

The above code works fine.

However, if I were to modify the function `dataInitialisation()` code into this;

```
function dataInitialisation()
{
  init_data = {
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          //categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999],
          categories: [1991, 1992],
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [30, 40],
        }
      ]
    };

  return init_data;
}
```

With the function above, the vue website turned blank and no error message appeared. What is wrong? Both functions look pretty much the same to me.

EDIT:
I noticed another strange behaviour. I added a meaningless line `x=2` to the function and this caused the website to go blank too.

```
function dataInitialisation()
{
  x = 2; //meaningless line caused website to go blank

  return {
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          //categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999],
          categories: [1991, 1992],
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [30, 40],
        }
      ]
    };
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `const`, `let` or `var` keyword before `init_data`. I'm not that familiar with Vue.js so I'm not sure it solves anything. However global variables will often lead to more bugs than their non-global counterparts. `const` and `let` will generally speaking produce the least amount of bugs since they have the smallest scope.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, boy do I feel stupid. I've been working on python for so long that I forgot about `var` and `let` on javascript. Thank you. Code is working now.
There was no error msg on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. I got the answer thanks to @3limin4t0r in the comment section.

I made a rookie mistake. I forgot the `let` in front of the variable `init_data`. There was no error message in javascript.

```
function dataInitialisation() {
  let init_data = {
    chartOptions: {
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: true,
        },
      },
      xaxis: {
        //categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999],
        categories: [1991, 1992],
      },
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "series-1",
        data: [30, 40],
      },
    ],
  };

  return init_data;
}
```

Comment: As you never modify it, I suggest using `const` instead. Or in this case just return the object directly: return {}